# Login is not persistent on any Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, login

I am a daily user of the Stack Exhange network, and I find it very frustrating to have to re-login at least once a day on each of the network sites that I am using.

It seems that somehow Stack Exchange is unable to remember my login for a long time. This problem seems to happen more and more often.

- What I am using to login: usually Google, but also Facebook.
- Browser: usually Safari 9 but also Chrome or Firefox.

**Is there something I can to so I would not have to endure the login and benefit from a persistent login?**

Comment: Is this a problem in all browsers or only Safari? Are you behind a proxy?